# Initializing Props within a State (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an image slider using the package react-slick. However, I want it to be a reusable component and not have to create a slider component for every page. So, I have tried writing it using props and states but I still cannot get it to work. My problem is that I don't know how to incorporate props into a state if such is even possible. The top block is my problem since I know that it does not read the props. I am trying to get data from another Image component that gets the image URL in my Home Page.

```
class ImageCarousel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    state = {
        images: [
            {url: {props.url1}},
            {url:{props.url2}},
            {url:{props.url3}},
            {url:{props.url4}} 
        ]
    }
    }
    render(){


        const settings = {
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: true,
            className: "slides"
          };
          return(
            <div className='ImageCarousel' style={{padding:30}}>
                <Slider {...settings}>
                <div>
                    {this.state.images[0].url}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {this.state.images[1].url}
                </div>

                 <div>
                    {this.state.images[2].url}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {this.state.images[3].url}
                </div>
                </Slider>
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default ImageCarousel;
```

Comment: try to replace props to this.props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you generate the url obejcts within the images array.

You are wrapping the props.url into a second object, which does not work:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
        this.state = {
            images: [
                {url: props.url1},
                {url: props.url2},
                {url: props.url3},
                {url: props.url4} 
            ]
        }
    }
```

To use default names, it has to be a variable:

```
const url = 'Test'
const obj = {url} // {url: Test}
```

Comment: @eizenyamakichi great, if that helped you, can you mark this answer as accepted so that other might find it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update constructor with following code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        images: [
            {url: {props.url1}},
            {url:{props.url2}},
            {url:{props.url3}},
            {url:{props.url4}} 
        ]
    }
}
```

Problem is how you set local state. `this` should be used to reference instance property, like `this.state`. While `state` behaves like global variable name.

Comment: I have tried this but it still does not recognize the props. Will try more options. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @eizenyamakichi Could you provide example how you set props?